# calculating time difference between two different times - millitary time

Tags: c

I have written the following code, which calculates the time difference between two given times. The task, however also asked for being cognizant of crossing the midnight. I can not think of a way to really deal with that in the code except for making sure the delta is reported as a positive value. I also searched online, and found some other code which does not seem to deal with it any better. Please note; I am asking about the algorithm. I am not looking for a function which does this. Here is my code:

```
struct time {
   int hour;
   int minutes;
   int seconds;
};

int main (void)

{
  struct time timeDiff (struct time now, struct time later);
  struct time result, one, two;
  printf("Enter the first time (hh:mm:sec): ");
  scanf("%i:%i:%i", &one.hour, &one.minutes, &one.seconds);
  printf("Enter the second time (hh:mm:sec): ");
  scanf("%i:%i:%i", &two.hour, &two.minutes, &two.seconds);
  result = timeDiff(one, two);
  printf("Time is:  %.2i:%.2i:%.2i\n", result.hour, result.minutes, result.seconds);
  return 0;
}
struct time timeDiff ( struct time now, struct time later)
  {
    struct time timeDiff;
    timeDiff.hour = later.hour - now.hour;
    timeDiff.minutes = later.minutes - now.minutes;
    timeDiff.seconds = later.seconds - now.seconds;
    return timeDiff;
  }
```

Here is the code I found online:

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct time
{
        int hour;
        int minute;
        int second;
};
int main(void)
{
        struct time  time3;
        //struct time get_time(struct time d);
        //struct time elapsed_time(struct time d, struct time e);
        int  convert_to_seconds(struct time d);
        int elapsed_time(int d, int e);
        struct time conver_to_normal_time(int a);
        struct time time1 =  { 3, 45,15};
        struct time time2 = { 9,  44, 03};
        int a, b, c;
        a = convert_to_seconds(time1);
        b = convert_to_seconds(time2);
        c = elapsed_time(a, b);
        time3 = conver_to_normal_time(c);
        printf(" %d:%d:%d", time3.hour, time3.minute, time3.second);
        return 0;
}
struct time get_time(struct time d)
{
        printf("Give me the time\n");
        scanf(" %d:%d:%d", &d.hour, &d.minute, &d.second);
}
int  convert_to_seconds(struct time d)
{
        struct time time1_seconds;
        int totalTime1_seconds;
        time1_seconds.hour = d.hour * 3600;
        time1_seconds.minute = d.second*60;
        time1_seconds.second = d.second;
        totalTime1_seconds = time1_seconds.hour + time1_seconds.minute + time1_seconds.second;
        return totalTime1_seconds;
        totalTime1_seconds = time1_seconds.hour + time1_seconds.minute + time1_seconds.second;
        return totalTime1_seconds;
}
int elapsed_time(int d, int  e)
{
        int result;
        result = d - e;
        return result;
}
struct time conver_to_normal_time(int a)
{
        struct time final_elapse_time;
        final_elapse_time.hour = a / 3600;
        final_elapse_time.minute = (a / 60) % 60;
        final_elapse_time.second = a % 60;
        return final_elapse_time;
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you have a solution to your problem (sign of delta), so what is the question?

Comment: You have made your own time subtraction without considering any "borrow". If that was hundreds, tens and units, you would know how to subtract it. For the seconds you would "borrow" 60 seconds from the minutes, etc. Try it on paper.

Comment: Hi Scott, yes I was trying to see if that is the best way to handle this and if I had made any incorrect assumptions. Vane's comment helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution you found online does handle the problem fairly well, it would only need to handle the change in days by adding the number of seconds in a day to the difference when below 0. Your problem ends up a little bigger, because in your solution you have a negative problem when any of the new values are smaller than the old. So if you have something like `00:00:50 => 00:01:10` you'll get `00:01:-40`. By translating to seconds, the difference is easier to count.

But, it sounds like you don't want to use the online solution, so the only way to get the elapsed time is to go through and add to the difference when necessary:

```
if (timeDiff.seconds < 0) {
    timeDiff.seconds += 60;
    timeDiff.minutes -= 1;
}
```

And similarly you'll have to handle minutes, then hours. It's also important that you do them in the order, to accumulate upwards. This stems from the fact that you're doing subtraction, but all of the values are connected so you're not carrying from minutes into seconds, hours into minutes, and then implicitly days into hours.

Comment: @Davek- I ran both codes and they both spit out negative values for the delta intervals with midnight/noon. I am working on another source code to calculate elapsed days, and then I can combine all this together. Your advise was what I needed to address the time difference issue.